# Generic function add element to list

Tags: c#, generics

I want to replace `AddQuickElement` and `AddRangeElement` with one generic function `AddElement<T>`. But how can i add generic element to `List<Base> list`. Activator do not work. Or what is better way to make this without reflection?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Base> list = new List<Base>();
        AddQuickElement(list,5);
        AddRangeElement(list, 5);
        AddElement<Quick>(list,5);
        Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void AddQuickElement(List<Base> list, int number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Quick());
        }
    }
    public static void AddRangeElement (List<Base> list, int number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Range());
        }
    }
    public static void AddElement<T>(List<Base> list, int number)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var element = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        // list.Add(element); // do not work
    }
}
public abstract class Base
{

}

public class Quick:Base
{

}

public class Range : Base
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to constraint the type parameter to `AddElement` method

```
public static void AddElement<T>(List<Base> list, int number) where T : Base, new()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new T());
    }
}
```

The type constraints `where T : Base, new()` mean that the type `T`

1. is derived from `Base`
2. has a public parameterless constructor.

(1) lets you add an instance of `T` to a `List<Base>`, (2) lets you create a new instance of `T` using `new T()`.